# How can I grep everything except the pattern and its next n lines?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep

I have a file:

names.dat:

```
AAAA
BBBB
```

text.dat:

```
AAAA
CTGCTTCGTCA
12127567612
BBBB
TCGACTACTAG
12331276318
CCCC
TCATCATACAT
23612763812
DDDD
GCTATCGCATC
23767263723
```

What I am trying to do is (using shell commands only) to exclude those lines from text.dat which are also present in names.dat along with (most importantly) with three lines after the common lines.

so basically the output shoud look somethign like:

```
CCCC
TCATCATACAT
23612763812
DDDD
GCTATCGCATC
23767263723
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$0]; next} $0 in a {i=0} ++i>3' names.dat text.dat
```

`NR==FNR` means that the total record number equals the record number of the current file (this is only true for the first file). Use the lines of `names.dat` to set keys in the array `a`. `next` skips to the next line of the input, ignoring any of the other commands in the one-liner. Whenever a line in `text.dat` matches an element of `a`, the counter `i` is reset to 0. Lines are only printed when `i` is greater than 3.

Testing it out:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$0]; next} $0 in a {i=0} ++i>3' names.dat text.dat 
CCCC
TCATCATACAT
23612763812
DDDD
GCTATCGCATC
23767263723
```

Answer (score 3):

If every line in text.dat is unique:

```
grep -Fxvf <(grep -f names.dat -A 2 text.dat | grep -v '^--' ) text.dat
```

Output:

```
CCCC
TCATCATACAT
23612763812
DDDD
GCTATCGCATC
23767263723
```

Comment: I was tempted to go along a similar route. It might also be worth mentioning that if the names are fixed, you can use the `-F` and/or `-x` to match fixed strings rather than regexes and to only match full lines.

Comment: I agree with you. Thank you. I have updated my answer to avoid matching substrings.

Comment: I've added `grep -v '^--'` because this problem/question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25733264/3776858

Comment: what if a line below CCCC is the same with a line below AAAA?

Comment: @lihao: See limitation in my first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

If:

1. There are no tabs in the file, and
2. There are no regex metacharacters in the patterns, then:

   ```
   paste -sd'\t\t\n' text.dat |
   grep -v -f <(mapfile -t a <names.dat;printf '^%s\t\n' "${a[@]}") |
   tr \\t \\n
   ```

has the advantage that it really compares the lines in groups of three, if that is what was desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `grep` command.

```
grep -v "`grep -f name.dat -A 2 text.dat`" text.dat
```

The output is below.

```
CCCC
TCATCATACAT
23612763812
DDDD
GCTATCGCATC
23767263723
```

Remark:
text.dat must have 2 lines between "AAAA" and "BBBB" also "BBBB" and "CCCC" because "2" is magic number...

Answer (score -1):

Regular expressions are closed under inversion. That means if you can match *x* using a regexp, you can match everything except *x* using a regexp.

Say `(AAAA\n|BBBB\n)` is your pattern, and you wanted to match that pattern and the next three lines. (Opposite of your problem.) Note that `\n` denotes a newline.

`(AAAA\n|BBBB\n)([^\n]*\n){3}` would get this. The `[^\n]` means “everything except a newline”. This expression finds your pattern, plus three complete lines. (Since `grep` doesn't support the curly bracket notation, you should use `egrep`.)

Pass the parameter `-v` to invert the expression.

Comment: You should try that; you'll find several issues: (1) Unless you specify `-E` (or `-P` in Gnu grep), `(` and `{` are not special. (2) You certainly meant `[^\n]*`; as written, the pattern would only match following lines with exactly one character, except that (3) grep matches *lines*, not arbitrary text. So you can never match a newline in a pattern.

Comment: The logic is impeccable, but the tool won't cooperate. With grep, you cannot match a pattern which spans more than one line. (Actually, you can do it with gnu grep, but it involves using `-zo` and including a literal newline in the pattern or using `-P`. And then you need to do the inversion manually, because there are no longer multiple lines.)