# Grep output adds extra dashes and newlines

Tags: grep

I'm using bash on a mac to run some grep and I'm using GNU grep installed with macports.  Anyway, I'm trying to query a fasta file (DNA sequences - sequence ID on one line with the DNA sequence on the following line) with grep to output a subset of the file based on a file list of strings to query.  Currently I have a list which is single words separated on a newline and the fasta file and am using the command

```
grep -A1 -f query_list.txt initial_file.fasta > query_subset.fasta
```

This almost produces the output I'm after but in the output file, after each sequence set that matches a string in the query file there is a double dash on a newline.  Not sure why it's happening .  I've tried removing them with sed

```
sed 's/\n--\n/\n' query_subset.fasta > final.fasta
```

but that doesn't work. If I use that same find and replace in textwrangler it works fine.

Anyway, as an example the files look like

query_list.txt

```
SpeciesA
SpeciesC
```

initial_file.fasta

```
>SpeciesA
ACGTGATCGATCGAT
>SpeciesB
ACGGGTCTTAGTATCG
>SpeciesC
ACGTACGATCTTCAGT
>SpeciesD
ACGTTCAGTCAGTTCAG
```

query_subset.fasta

```
>SpeciesA
ACGTGATCGATCGAT
--
>SpeciesC
ACGTACGATCTTCAGT
--
```

I need this to be done via the command line as I'm trying to implement it into a script to automate some sample processing.

Any input is greatly appreciated!
Cheers,
Tris

Comment: The `--` **group separator** is always inserted between groups of lines when either `-A, -B, or -C` context specifiers are used. See one of the `sed` solutions below to remove.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
grep -A1 -f query_list.txt initial_file.fasta | sed '/^--/d' > final.fasta
```

or

```
grep -A1 -f query_list.txt initial_file.fasta | grep -v '^--' > final.fasta
```

Comment: Are you sure you want `^` in `grep -v '^--' > final.fasta`? Never mind - you are correct :)

Comment: Thanks! Both of these worked! Although I get an extra newline at the end of the final.fasta? is that just a grep thing?

Comment: Sorry, with your query_list.txt and initial_file.fasta I can not reproduce this.

Answer (score 2):

According to the man pages:

> -A NUM, --after-context=NUM
>           Print NUM  lines  of  trailing  context  after  matching  lines.
>           Places  a  line  containing  --  between  contiguous  groups  of
>           matches.

I tried the following and it worked:

```
cat query_list.txt | xargs -I {} grep -A1 {} initial_file.txt  > query_subset.fasta
```

I'm not quite sure why the input patterns are treated differently when they come from std in, so it's probably better to just strip off the offending lines:

```
grep -A1 -f query_list.txt initial_file.txt | grep -v "\-\-" >  query_subset.fasta
```

Comment: Thanks! your second line worked for me, for some reason the first just gave me a blank file.